# Failed to use selenium to automatically click the link in a website

Tags: python, selenium

I want to use selenium to automatically log in a website(https://www.cypress.com/) and download some materials.
I successfully open the website using selenium. But when I use selenium to click the "Log in" button. It shows this:
[Access Denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eI9cB.png)

Here is my code:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

class Cypress():
    def extractData(self):
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:chromedriver.exe")
        browser.get("https://www.cypress.com/")
        sleep(5)
        element = browser.find_element_by_link_text("Log in")
        sleep(1)
        element.click()
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Cypress()
    a.extractData()
    pass
```

Can anyone give me some idea?

Answer (score 0):

The website is protected using Akamai CDN, services, or whatever is loaded there.
I took a quick glance and it seems like the Akamai service worker is up, but I don't see any sensor data protection, selenium is simply detected as webdriver (and plenty other things) and flagged, try to login using requests, or ask the website owner to give you API access for your project.
Akamai cookies are up, so surely the protection is too, the 301 you got is the bot protection stopping you from automating something on a protected endpoint.

Comment: Thank you for your help. At least I get to know the reason.